# Return tensorflow layer outputs from a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have written the following model in a separate file :

```
def fun(X,num_actions,hiddens,layer_norm,keep_prob = 0.5):



    out = X

    out = layers.fully_connected(out, num_outputs=hidden[0], activation_fn=None)
    out1 = tf.nn.relu(out)

    drop_out = tf.nn.dropout(out1, keep_prob)

    out2 = layers.fully_connected(drop_out, num_outputs=hidden[1], activation_fn=None)
    out2 = tf.nn.relu(out2)

    out3 = layers.fully_connected(out2, num_outputs=hidden[2], activation_fn=None)
    out3 = tf.nn.relu(out3)


    out4 = layers.fully_connected(out3, num_outputs=num_actions, activation_fn=None)

   return out4
```

I am calling this function in a class defined in different file like this :

```
class a(): 
    def __init__(scope):
     with tf.variable_scope(scope):
        # Build the graph
        self._build_model(...) #this calls the function fun()
```

I want to get values of `out1,drop_out,out2,out3,out4` returned from `fun()` function but tensorflow gives me errors.

I read some posts to get the any tensor using `tf.get_variable()`. But I don't know how to get these layer outputs as I didnt name them & searching them in the the global variable space is a big task.

Do you think these tensors will be available under the scope name I am using in `class a()` 
 ? My final aim is to write these values to tensorboard.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to get values of out1,drop_out,out2,out3,out4 returned from fun() function but tensorflow gives me errors.

You'll need to `return` those values if you want to get them.

> but tensorflow gives me errors.

can't help you if we don't know what the errors are